# Django ElasticSearch rest framework suggestion duplicate result

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am writing a API which will auto-suggest when I a type something but it is working, it is returning the results without query and even sometime duplicate value.

This is is my API views:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.filter_backends import (
    SuggesterFilterBackend
)

from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.viewsets import DocumentViewSet

from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.constants import (
    SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
)

from users.paginations import LotPagination



class SuggestionsAPIView(DocumentViewSet):
    document = ProductDocument
    serializer_class =  ProdcutTitleSerializer

    filter_backends = [
        SuggesterFilterBackend,

    ]

    suggester_fields = {
        'title': {
            'field': 'title',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            ],
            'options': {
                'size': 20, 
                'skip_duplicates':True,
            },
        },
    }
```

and when I make API request, I pass parameter like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/product/?title=Ar
```

In my database, there are lots of duplicate title but when it return the search results in suggestion, it should not show the duplicate title.

Can anyone please help me in this case? Why is it not working? or should  I do it another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
'skip_duplicates':True,
```

it will remove duplicate elements in your results. you can remove that from your code.